# Python Multiprocessing kills main Program

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I got a Problem with one of my Python-Programs and mutliprocessing module

Every time I start a Process, I get a Raspbian Error, where I can Kill the Process or cancel killing. When I hit cancel, or Ok, the Program freezes.

I hope to get some help :)

```
def start(self): 
   t=multiprocessing.Process(target=self.function)
   t.start()
```

The `self.function` is a function that gets data from a port and saves it to an Array. It is a Looping function, that loops itself

Comment: If multiple processes get data from the same port then it can happen. Try to use `Threading` or make sure that each process of `self.function` reads from a different port.

Comment: The process of grabbing the data is probably not thread-safe. You are creating a racing condition where multiple processes are grabbing the same data. Not sure what the rest of your code is doing but you may want to look into a single thread reading the data and then other code processing the data.